# Ошибка при сборке проекта в FlashDevelop

Tags: flash, haxe

Пытаюсь собрать почти пустой проект в FD, язык Haxe, либа HaxeFlixel. Сначала собирался нормально, спустя время перестал, вылетает с ошибкой `Sys_error("export/flash/bin/Danmaku.swf: Permission denied")`. Антивирус отключил. Windows 7 x32

Comment: Очень странно, перезапуск среды не помогает, но помогает запуск swf из /flash/bin/

Comment: По симптомам похоже, что этот файл в чём-то открыт, и система не даёт его из-за этого перезаписать.

Comment: FlashPlayer (или adb) может висеть в памяти.